# How to concatenate and use spread operator in dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, radix-sort

This is js code of doing it!

```
 nums = [].concat(...digitBuckets);
```

how can i implement it in dart?

```
nums=[].addAll(...digitBucketsd);//facing problem here and confused
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator is designed to insert array elements into another array or to map its elements to function arguments.

The mistake is that: elements of array are used as arguments of `concat` function, but `concat` function requires array as argument but not its elements as arguments:

replace

```js
nums = [].concat(...digitBuckets);
nums = [].addAll(...digitBucketsd);
```

with

```js
nums = [].concat(digitBuckets);
nums = [].addAll(digitBucketsd);
```

or with spread

```js
nums = [...digitBuckets];
nums = [...digitBucketsd];
```

also `digitBucketsd` is present in question instead of `digitBuckets`

Comment: hey..the js code is perfectly working..I am trying to watch js DSA course and coding in dart..Now currently in radix sort...In js they used

Comment: nums = [].concat(...digitBuckets);

Comment: above code  too add two array in js they concat method is used ..in dart its addAll.

Comment: i am just converting js radix sort to dart code!